# How to avoid these tedious findViewById() calls?

Tags: android, findviewbyid, android-viewbinding

I have a simple layout file with two TextViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tile_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample text"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tile_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="20.0"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I include this layout in some places in my app. In my last case I had to include this 4 times. To find and set text to these two text views in the individual included layouts I have to find an id to one layout and from there find an id to two text views. And repeat 3 times for all included layouts. This leads to some ugly and horrible to maintain code:

```
@Override
public void setStatsValues(String today, String week, String month, String total) {
    // this is so tedious.
    View layoutDay = findViewById(R.id.layout_stats_day);
    View layoutWeek = findViewById(R.id.layout_stats_week);
    View layoutMonth = findViewById(R.id.layout_stats_month);
    View layoutTotal = findViewById(R.id.layout_stats_total);
    TextView tvDayTitle = layoutDay.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_title);
    TextView tvWeekTitle = layoutWeek.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_title);
    TextView tvMonthTitle = layoutMonth.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_title);
    TextView tvTotalTitle = layoutTotal.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_title);
    TextView tvDayValue = layoutDay.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_value);
    TextView tvWeekValue = layoutWeek.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_value);
    TextView tvMonthValue = layoutMonth.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_value);
    TextView tvTotalValue = layoutTotal.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_value);
    tvDayTitle.setText("Today");
    tvWeekTitle.setText("Week");
    tvMonthTitle.setText("Month");
    tvTotalTitle.setText("Total");
    tvDayValue.setText(today);
    tvWeekValue.setText(week);
    tvMonthValue.setText(month);
    tvTotalValue.setText(total);
}
```

How can I avoid this monstrosity?

Comment: The solution is the [viewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: viewBinding is not available in every IDE, so bad idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding):

Add in your build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Create a layout `activity_test.xml`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then in your `Activity`:

Kotlin

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityTestBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityTestBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    binding.text1.text = "Hello"
    binding.text2.text = "....."

}
```

---

Java

```
private ActivityTestBinding binding;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityTestBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);

    binding.text1.setText("hello");

}
```

Comment: i added a java version to your kotlin answer, as OP's question was asked in Java, i do agree with your answer though :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks for your feedback. I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) to automatically do all the `findViewById` stuff - it generates a "Binding" class named after your layout, and every `View` in the layout with an `id` gets a reference.

So in your case you'd just be able to do `dayBinding.tv_tile_value.setText("today")`

If you don't want to do that, you could refactor all the repeated code into a function, like

```
private void setTheThings(int layoutResId, String title, String value) {
    View layout = findViewById(layoutResId)
    layout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_tile_title).setText(title)
    layout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_tile_value).setText(value)
}
```

(or whatever to cast to TextView) and then just call that for each layout ID

Comment: U raised a night point bruh, this way it's easier as well. I agree

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are making the code tedious your own self. There is no need to find a view by first going to the parent then the child and so on.

Instead of:

```
    View layoutDay = findViewById(R.id.layout_stats_day);
    View layoutWeek = findViewById(R.id.layout_stats_week);
    View layoutMonth = findViewById(R.id.layout_stats_month);
    View layoutTotal = findViewById(R.id.layout_stats_total);
    TextView tvDayTitle = layoutDay.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_title);
    TextView tvWeekTitle = layoutWeek.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_title);
    TextView tvMonthTitle = layoutMonth.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_title);
    TextView tvTotalTitle = layoutTotal.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_title);
    TextView tvDayValue = layoutDay.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_value);
    TextView tvWeekValue = layoutWeek.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_value);
    TextView tvMonthValue = layoutMonth.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_value);
    TextView tvTotalValue = layoutTotal.findViewById(R.id.tv_tile_value);
```

You can just do it like this (just differ the ids, i mean use different ids for each view):

```
    TextView tvDayTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_day_title);
    TextView tvWeekTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_week_title);
    TextView tvMonthTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_month_title);
    TextView tvTotalTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_total_title);
```

Comment: you raise a valid point, although your last line in your example isn't entirely valid, seems to be copied incorrectly